# Is it more efficient to loop though (a bunch of csv lines) or (list contains dictionary)?

Tags: python, json, list, csv, dictionary

I can download the data as `csv` or `json`. If the data is in csv, I use `response.text` to convert it to text before inserting it into the dictionary. The data sample looks like this:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adjusted_close,Volume
1966-07-05,10.9176,11.0872,10.836,10.9176,0.1327,388800
1966-07-06,11.5024,11.5024,10.836,11.5024,0.1398,692550
1966-07-07,11.0872,11.7936,11.0008,11.0872,0.1347,1858950
```

Then I must loop through all of the data points and insert them into the database using the following code:

```
for ticker, csv_data in data.items():
        reader = csv.reader(csv_data.splitlines())
        next(reader)
        for input_data in reader:
            input_data = [ticker] + [input_data[0], input_data[1], input_data[2], input_data[3], input_data[4]]
```

I can also use `response.json()` and the data will be in bunch of lists and dictionaries like this:

```
[{'date': '2021-02-09', 'open': 123.41, 'high': 123.49, 'low': 122.36, 'close': 123.24, 'adjusted_close': 121.7803, 'volume': 1988260}, {'date': '2021-02-10', 'open': 124.59, 'high': 125.74, 'low': 123.88, 'close': 125.08, 'adjusted_close': 123.5985, 'volume': 1112597}]
```

Then I'll use the following code to loop through all of the data points and insert them into the database:

```
 input_data_columns = "date open high low close".split(" ")
 for ticker, symbol_data in data.items():
     for date_data in symbol_data: 
            input_data = (ticker,) + tuple(date_data.get(col) for col in input_data_columns)
```

My question is which type of data is more efficient and faster (with the same amount of datapoints)?

Comment: Have you tried measuring the performance difference using the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)? Depending on the size of your data (and the speed of your network) the answer may be "it doesn't matter", but you're in the best position to make that determination.

Comment: @larsks Yes, but the result is inconsistent. Sometimes csv faster, sometimes the other...

Comment: If there is little data, then what's the difference what to use? If a lot - better through pandas.

Comment: If both ways produce the same exact result, I would create a bunch of fake data, identical data in both formats. Do 1-10 million data points, so you can see visible differences.  Then do benchmarks as @larsks suggested.  You can create the data using [Faker](https://pypi.org/project/Faker/)

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose is to make your code run much faster, then use pandas library, this way you can read it all at once (and fast), and use vectorization- the idea of making operations (and calculations) over a vector - which usually is a column in a dataframe.

you can read the csv file using:

```
filename = "your_file_name.csv"

import pandas as pd
your_data = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

And to answer your question- depends on your data types and size.
the first option may be faster when you have a large dataset and simple datatypes such as integers/booleans/short strings.

If the datatypes are not simple ones or you have a small dataset- I can't tell. only experiments on your data will tell.